# Finding $f'(0)$ when $f(x)=\int\limits_0^x\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I need to show that $f'(0)=0$ for
$$
f(x)=\int\limits_0^x\sin\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)dt
$$
But fundamental theorem of calculus is unapplicable here. What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean, show that $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$?  Because $f'(x)\neq 0$ for most values of $x$

Comment: Sorry, that is my inadvertence

Comment: Sorry, you are right... again

Comment: $f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$.  Probably you'll need to find the limit by "squeezing".

Comment: How to find this limit? L'Hopital's rule doesn't work too!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163717/find-the-derivative-of-the-primitive-of-a-discontinous-function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one approach:

- Use integration by parts to show that $f(x)=x^2\cos(1/x)-\int_0^x 2t\cos(1/t)dt$ for $x\neq 0$.
- Use this to show that $\left|\dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right|\leq 2|x|$.

Comment: Then $0\leq |f'(0)|\leq\lim\limits_{x\to 0} 2|x|=0$. Right?

Comment: I do not entirely follow the logic of your comment, but e.g. you could use the so-called squeeze theorem, observing that $0<|f(x)/x|<2|x|$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}2|x| = 0$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, hence by definition $f'(0)$ exists and is $0$.

Comment: Note that if you could assume that $f'(0)$ exists then this would be very easy, because $f$ is an even function so $f'(0)=0$ if it exists.  ($f(x)=f(-x)\implies f'(x)=-f'(-x)$.)

Comment: You are so smart!

Answer (score 7):

To strengthen the convergence of an integral, a integration by parts is always a good idea.
Here we have
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)
&=\int_0^x\sin\left(\frac 1t \right) dt\\
&= \left[ t^2 \cos\left(\frac 1t \right)\right]_0^x - \int_0^x 2t\cos\left(\frac 1t \right)dt\\
&= x^2 \cos\left(\frac 1x \right) - \int_0^x 2t\cos\left(\frac 1t \right)dt
\end{aligned}$$
You can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus for the second term, since it is the integral of a continuous function. The first term is a $O(x^2)$, so it is differentiable at zero with null derivative. In the end, we get $f'(0) = 0$.

[*Reminder* — A function $f$ is derivable at zero with derivative $a$ if and only if $f(x) = f(0) + ax + o(x)$ when $x\to 0$.]

Comment: Your solution is more detailed but Jonas Meyer for the first.

Comment: @Jataga — Detailed solutions are longer to write ! (Just teasing you, I don't mind your choice ;))

Comment: Ok I've got another unanswered question. I will be glad to accept your solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to show that $f$ is differentiable in an interval around $0$ and apply [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).